# Run Javascript as part of a web service (i.e. not from browser)

Tags: javascript, php, curl

So I am in a tight spot, and I hope SO community can help me.The situation is this:

I am building a PHP script to consume a web service of our partner. Our partner has a very specific has algorithm using which I need to sign my payload. However this hash algorithm does not have support in PHP. In the only library I found that supports this is cryptoJS. This is also the library used by our partner.

For testing I take the payload and manually run a JS script in browser, which spits out the hash, which I copy into my PHP code and send to the web service  - and everything works fine.

However now I need to make this PHP script a CRON! How can I integrate the part where I call CryptoJS from the browser and get the hash?

The JS code is very simple:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha3.js"></script>
<script>
var payload = '<my-pay-load>';
var secretkey = "my-secret";
var payloadhash = CryptoJS.HashAlgorithmFn(payload + secretkey);
document.write(payloadhash);
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use PhantomJS, it simulates a webbrowser on the server.

Comment: There's v8js extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php

Comment: re-write the hash algorithm and such in php ? its all possible using the unix system side crypt functions and php encryption mcrypt() and bcrypt() etc.

Comment: @Dave: If could rewrite a complicated JS hash algorithm in PHP I would not be asking this question :) j/k

Comment: Could always use an SHA3 extension to php such as this one https://github.com/strawbrary/php-sha3 until sha3 is embedded in to php core or use a website/service to do it for you such as https://sha3.me/